# How do I write proper quote marks without having to write the unicode?

Tags: linux, configuration, manjaro

Is there a way I can configure Manjaro Cinnamon to write quote marks without having to write <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> `275D` for `❝` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> `275E` for `❞`?

I'm using an ISO Tenkeyless keyboard. Specifically Filco Ninja Majestouch-2, Tenkeyless, MX Brown Tactile. With spanish layout.

Comment: Which keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: What program do you need to write those quotes in?

Comment: I want to write the quotes mainly in firefox.